# jupyter nbconvert sticky bit runtime warning

Tags: python, jupyter, nbconvert

When I run `jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html toy_notebook.ipynb` with jupyter version 4.3.0 and python 3.6 on macOS 10.12.5,  I get the following warning:

> [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook toy_notebook.ipynb to html
>   [NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
>   /Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py:157:
>   RuntimeWarning: Failed to set sticky bit on
>   '/var/folders/nr/1n4j77yx7g93kzr2mrwwdlgm0000gq/T': [Errno 1]
>   Operation not permitted:
>   '/var/folders/nr/1n4j77yx7g93kzr2mrwwdlgm0000gq/T'   RuntimeWarning,
>   /Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py:157:
>   RuntimeWarning: Failed to set sticky bit on
>   '/var/folders/nr/1n4j77yx7g93kzr2mrwwdlgm0000gq/T': [Errno 1]
>   Operation not permitted:
>   '/var/folders/nr/1n4j77yx7g93kzr2mrwwdlgm0000gq/T'   RuntimeWarning,

A stack trace is here. I think it's an issue with setting sticky bits on temporary connection files that are being created?

> File
>   "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py",
>   line 172, in from_filename
>   return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
>   File
>   "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py",
>   line 190, in from_file
>
> ```
> return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/html.py",
>   line 84, in from_notebook_node
>
> ```
> return super(HTMLExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)                File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py",
> ```
>
> line 268, in from_notebook_node
>
> ```
> nb_copy, resources = super(TemplateExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py",
>   line 132, in from_notebook_node
>
> ```
> nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)                               File
> ```
>
> "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py",
>   line 309, in _preprocess
>
> ```
> nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)        File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py",
> ```
>
> line 47, in **call**
>
> ```
> return self.preprocess(nb,resources)       File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py",
> ```
>
> line 237, in preprocess
>
> ```
> cwd=path)                                  File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py",
> ```
>
> line 217, in start_new_kernel
>
> ```
> km.start_kernel(**kwargs)                  File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py",
> ```
>
> line 238, in start_kernel
>
> ```
> self.write_connection_file()               File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py",
> ```
>
> line 431, in write_connection_file
>
> ```
> kernel_name=self.kernel_name               File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py",
> ```
>
> line 157, in write_connection_file
>
> ```
> RuntimeWarning,                            File "/Users/zblanton/anaconda/lib/python3.6/warnings.py", line 99, in
> ```
>
> _showwarnmsg
>       msg.file, msg.line)                        File "dodo.py", line 16, in warn_with_traceback
>       traceback.print_stack(file=log)

For what it's worth, the notebook I was using looks like this:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "be nice"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "9\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "print(3 * 3)"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.6.2"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/pull/201#issuecomment-314269710) - it's a warning that you can safely ignore, and a future release of jupyter_client will silence the warning.

Comment: awesome, thanks! glad to know I'm not the only one facing this lol